# Extract year and month from a timestamp using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the year and month from an  timestamp using regex.

Example :

I have a  timestamp: `20130923161057`. I need to extract the year `2013` and month `09` using regex.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work? If not, what is the error?

Comment: String#substring() would be my way to go... 0-3 and 4-5

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Java has [parsers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this purpose.

Comment: are month and day formatted with leading zero?

Comment: I tried \\d{4} it was not working. and it need to be an regex.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I think PhilippSander has the answer: for this, OP doesn't even have to have any kind of parsers...

Comment: And why regex? Java provides many other ways to do it

Comment: @iamnotmaynard good idea! but that could create a lot of overhead

Comment: @DaveHowes Yes but that was the requirement . I was not able to change it

Comment: This regexp-requirement sounds like homework to me.

Comment: If the format is always going to be exactly "yyyyMMddhhmmss" then @PhilippSander 's suggestion is the simplest.

Comment: i made a mistake in my first comment but posted a corrected answer with argumentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})\\d{8}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("20130923161057");
if (matcher.find()) {
    int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    // do something with year/month
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be using [String.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

But if you want regex it would be `(\d{4})(\d{2}).*`
Please search for examples of extracting groups out of regex match.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need regex, you can do something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<year>\\d{4,4})(?<month>\\d{2,2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher("20130923161057");
if (m.find())
{
    String year = m.group("year");
    String month = m.group("month");

    System.out.println(year + "    " + month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx isn't really useful here. You have no advantage compared to java functions like [String#substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) which are easier to read:

```
String timestamp = "20130923161057";

Sring year = timestamp.substring(0, 4);
String month = timestamp.substring(4, 6);
```

output:

```
year = 2013
month = 09
```